# How to select data from 'logged in user' from database to a graph

Tags: php, mysql, graph, charts

I need help with some code. I want to **select** data from mySQL to a **graph** on my web page. 
The data **must** be from the **current** **logged** **in** **user**, and when I select data to a card it works fine, but when I select it to a graph the graph disappears.

I'm using this code for the cards, and it works fine:

```
 $sql = "SELECT energyexpenditure FROM energy4project WHERE user_id =  '{$_SESSION["user_id"]}' ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 1;";
```

This is the code for my current graph that **don't** show data based on logged in user:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "`blabla";
        $pwd = "blabla";
        $db = "blabla";
        $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }


         $sql = "SELECT energyexpenditure, time_stamp FROM energy4project ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 7;";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);


$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

mysqli_close($conn);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

When I implement the code from the cards in the graph code it doesn't work.
Why does the `SELECT WHERE user = '{$_SESSION["user_id"]}` not work in the graphs?

Comment: Fast fix: `{$_SESSION['user_id']}` (use single quotes for index name when using string interpolation) . But you better start using prepared statements with placeholders. Read [how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I tried it with single quotes,   $sql = "SELECT energyexpenditure, time_stamp FROM energy4project {$_SESSION['user_id']} ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 7;";  and I put it in the graph file, but my file just disappears?

Comment: You omitted `WHERE user_id = `.

Comment: I'm sorry I mean I used this code... ````$sql = "SELECT energyexpenditure, time_stamp FROM energy4project WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION['user_id']} ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 7;"; ````. And my graph still disappears

Answer (score 0):

If I understood good your Mysql query return an empty result. Try to modify your code as follows:

```
if(!$result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "query error."; 
    die();
}

$data = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}


/* free result set */
$result->free();

/* close connection */
$conn->close();

//uncomment the below line if you want to check de result of your mysql query because it seems be good.
//var_dump($data); die(); echo "<pre>"; 

echo json_encode($data);
```

So if you don't have any mysql error, verify your database name, table name are correctly and if it has data in your table.

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Regards

Comment: The graph works just fine, but when I add WHERE user_id = .... the graph disappears..

Comment: $userId = $_SESSION["user_id"];
Add this to your query 
$sql = "SELECT energyexpenditure, time_stamp FROM energy4project WHERE user_id = $userId ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 7;